# Get average per partition and keep all results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
company date_num profit
A        EPOCH   12
B        EPOCH   17
A        EPOCH   7
C        EPOCH   9
```

I would like to calculate average per company and keep the profit column:

```
company date_num profit  AVG
A        EPOCH   12      9.5
A        EPOCH   7       9.5
B        EPOCH   17      17
C        EPOCH   9       9
```

So the average column will have the same number(avg) for all rows of a company, and will calculate a single average for all company values.

I tried:

```
SELECT company,
AVG(profit) as avg
FROM history
WHERE date_num >= 1617235200 AND date_num <= 1619913600 AND company IN('A','B')
GROUP BY company
```

Which produce a single line result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVG` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT company, AVG(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY company) AS avg
FROM history
WHERE date_num >= 1617235200 AND date_num <= 1619913600 AND company IN ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: oh stupid me, i tried this already but did it wrong. thanks. Is this makes the query MUCH slower ?

Comment: When using a window function, the database will do the aggregation over the entire result set.  It should not perform much differently than your original query actually.